# Auto input credentials when prompted in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

I am a newbie to ruby. We have our install process automated in ruby. I am facing an issue on making ruby script adapt to changes in shell script.

```
execute "update_imports" do
cwd import_home
command "./Import.sh #{download_dir}/#{import_file} #{user} #{Shellwords.escape(password)}"
action :run
end
```

The Import.sh is modified such that now it asks for username and password (doesn't take username and password as arguments as earlier)

```
Earlier:
./Import.sh /tmp/importTest.xml test1 password

Now:
./Import.sh /tmp/importTest.xml
username: test1
password:
```

I want to modify the ruby file to adapt to this change. Can you suggest the best way to do so? I tried to do some searching and learning but being pretty new to ruby, I am clueless.

Comment: Are you using a framework or is this your own DSL?

Comment: No.. we are not using any framework

Comment: The best way is probably to change `Import.sh` in a way that allows username and password to be passed either as arguments or via a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open3` in the ruby standard library:

```
download_dir = "./test/dir"
shell_command = "./Import.sh #{download_dir}"
username = "username"
password = "password"

Open3.popen3("shell_command") do |input, output, error, thread|
  input.puts(username) # answers the username prompt
  input.puts(password) # answers the password prompt
  puts output.read # prints the output of the script so far
end
```